# Auto refresh webview

Tags: html, google-chrome-app

I'm creating a webview Chrome app that should auto refresh its window.

I've tried using html meta refresh, but it didn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Most magic happens here -->
    <webview id="webview" src="URL" partition="persist:applicationize"></webview>
    <!-- Embed script to capture keystrokes -->
    <script src="../js/embed.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, is a chrome app, but google dont call apps, now call everything extensions, i dont know why...

Comment: Where do you see it named as an extension?

Comment: Anyway, AFAIK you can't reload the main app page so you'll have to change the contents via standard DOM methods manually or put everything into an iframe so your main page contains only the iframe, and all your UI is inside the iframe where you'll be able to use auto reload.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the page  using javascript like this

```
location.reload();
```

so to refresh every 5  seconds you can do the following

```
setInterval( () => {
  location.reload();
}, 5000)
```

The code should be  in your extension as when you reload the page, the page's code will stop execution.

OR

You can fire the setTimeout function after the  page is loaded which will execute the refresh after 5  seconds like this

```
setTimeout( () => {
  location.reload();
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Sorry, where i place that code? can u show me a example?